# Intellij IDEA 12 doesn't recognize Playframework 2.1 (java) dependencies set in Build.scala

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.1

I have the following dependencies added to my Build.scala and they work perfectly (no compilation errors), but Intellij IDEA 12 doesn't recognize them. It shows them red highlighted.

```
"com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1-RC2"
```

[image]

It is quite annoying as you can see :)

Is it possible to fix it? In google guice case, I put its jars into /lib folder (so I have the library twice, one in /lib and the other in /target folder) and then IDEA doesn't show errors for it, but I don't like this workaround and can't do the same for the Mailer plugin.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you rerun `play idea`? IntelliJ is not "supervising" the `Build.scala` file so it has no way of knowing that you have added new dependencies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to rerun the `play idea` command in order to get IntelliJ to know that there are new dependencies added.

I normally enter the `play` CLI and then run:

```
idea no-sbt-build-module with-sources=yes
```

This will download the sources for the dependencies (if they exist) and also make sure that the output path will be correct and that modules are not loaded several times.

Comment: Thanks maba! running play idea worked fine, however when I tried with idea no-sbt-build-module with-sources=yes, play didn't recognized none of them. I had this problem before with with-sources=yes.

Comment: @monkeydeveloper You'll have to enter the play CLI first, or enter the arguments inside quotes like `play "idea no-sbt-build-module with-sources=yes"`. But I prefer to first type `play` and enter the CLI and then enter the above mentioned line.